# Iterative spearman correlation with cor.test?

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, iteration, correlation

I'm a beginner in R and I'm having some problems with trying to create an iterative cor.test in R. I have a table with 8 different sampling spots (columns 1 to 8) and for each sampling spot I measured a variable (VARIABLE1, first row) and the presence of a series of species (OTUs on the rows). Here you can see an excerpt of my table (called "matrix"):

```
row.names   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
VARIABLE1   1565    1809,83 1019    1909,83 756,33  631,67  529,83  436
OTU1    0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0
OTU2    0   0   0   0   0   0   13  0
OTU3    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
OTU4    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
OTU5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
OTU6    0   0   19  0   9   236 59  2
OTU7    0   0   0   2   4   2   3   0
OTU8    0   0   10  5   0   0   7   0
OTU9    6   0   13  2   0   0   17  6
OTU10   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0
OTU11   4   13  0   0   2   1   2   0
OTU12   0   0   0   0   0   101 1   0
```

I want to calculate spearman's correlation between VARIABLE1 and each and every OTUs. So VARIABLE1 has to remain fixed, while the OTU has to change every time.

I tried with "lapply", but it did not work:

```
flip_matrix <- t(matrix)
variable1 <- flip_matrix[,1]
lapply(flip_matrix[1:107], function(x) cor.test(x, variable1, alternative='two.sided', method='spearman'))
 Error in cor.test.default(x, shoot_growth, alternative = "two.sided",  :  
            'x' e 'y' must be of the same length
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks to everyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using apply instead of a loop. You get also the p values of the tests.

```
df <- read.table(header=T,dec=",",text=c("row.names   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
VARIABLE1   1565    1809,83 1019    1909,83 756,33  631,67  529,83  436
                                         OTU1    0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0
                                         OTU2    0   0   0   0   0   0   13  0
                                         OTU3    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                                         OTU4    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                                         OTU5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
                                         OTU6    0   0   19  0   9   236 59  2
                                         OTU7    0   0   0   2   4   2   3   0
                                         OTU8    0   0   10  5   0   0   7   0
                                         OTU9    6   0   13  2   0   0   17  6
                                         OTU10   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0
                                         OTU11   4   13  0   0   2   1   2   0
                                         OTU12   0   0   0   0   0   101 1   0"))
dft <- t(df[,-1]) 
res <- apply(dft[,-1], 2, function(x,y) cor.test(x,y,method = "spearman"),dft[,1])
data.frame(do.call(rbind,res))
```

or use the rcorr function of the Hmisc package

```
library(Hmisc)
rcorr(dft,type = "spearman")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
matrix <- matrix(
  c(1565, 1809.83, 1019, 1909.83, 756.33,  631.67, 529.83, 436,
    0,   0  , 0  , 0   ,0   ,3   ,0   ,0,
    0,   0,   0 ,  0   ,0   ,0   ,13  ,0,
    5 ,  0  , 0 ,  0   ,0   ,0   ,0   ,0,
    0 ,  0,   0  , 0   ,0   ,0   ,0   ,0,
    0 ,  0  , 0   ,0   ,0   ,0   ,0   ,2,
    0 ,  0  , 19  ,0   ,9   ,236 ,59  ,2,
    0 ,  0  , 0   ,2   ,4   ,2   ,3   ,0,
    0 ,  0  , 10  ,5   ,0   ,0   ,7   ,0,
    6 ,  0  , 13  ,2   ,0   ,0   ,17  ,6,
    0,   0 ,  0   ,0   ,0   ,3   ,0   ,0,
    4,   13,  0   ,0   ,2   ,1   ,2   ,0,
    0 ,  0 ,  0   ,0   ,0   ,101 ,1   ,0), ncol = 8, byrow = T)

rownames(matrix) = c("VARIABLE1", paste("OTU", 1:12, sep = ""))

test <- list()
for (i in 2:nrow(matrix)) {
  test[[i]] <- cor.test(x = matrix[1,], y = matrix[i,], alternative="two.sided", method="spearman")
}
```

I do however get warning messages, probably due to the small sample size.